# How to create a new dial connection in java?

Tags: java, networking, modem

In my application user has to create a new dial up network connection in windows but i want to do this programmatically.Is there any API present in java that can help me for creating new network connection.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for an API to control his phone line dial-up modem.

Comment: I am creating a similar application to NowSMS. In NowSMS you can send sms using mobile wap gateway. if you connect your mobile device with pc and configure NowSMS, you can see a new connection in your network connections and even it connecting and disconnecting also from software itself. that's what i want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create a Windows dial-up networking connection using pure Java.  You might consider using Java to call built-in Windows command line programs though.  See this as a starting point: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555935

Answer (score 0):

What do you need the network connection for? If you want to talk to another client of your application or a server written in Java, you can use the [Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Sun used to have a phone/telecom API that might help, but I think it has not been developed on in years... since probably about the same time dial-up died. :-)

Your best option may be to look for a native API that does what you want and write a JNI wrapper around it. Alternately, if you are lucky some google searching might come up with someone who has already done that.

Good luck.