# Using dial-up modems or GSM modems in Java

Tags: java, telephony, modem, dial-up

I want to communicate with my [DFM-562IS D-Link](ftp://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Modem/DFM-562IS/Data_sh/DS_DFM562IS-ENG-01.pdf) modem (that is connected to my computer's mainboard via a PCI slot) using Java. The goal is listening for incoming calls and receive a code that the user enters on the other-side after connection (by his/her phone's keypad).

So far my searching on the Internet didn't give me anything useful and I found some closed old threads only ([Here](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/14224/connecting-modem-via-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988421/how-to-create-a-new-dial-connection-in-java) for example).

I just want to know if is it possible?  and If so, give me a guildline please.

I really appreciate for shedding a light on this issue.
Thanks in advance

**Update:**

If the goal is achievable with **GSM modems**, please provide the related solutions for the issue in your answer also.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's possible, but I doubt it's very popular these days!

I don't know much about modems, but presumably if you can't find a higher-level library then you could communicate with them via the serial port using the [Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) or [RxTx](https://github.com/rxtx/rxtx).

To see an exmaple of communication with a GSM modem, have a look at [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/).

---

If you are looking to support [IVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_voice_response), then you may not be able to find Java support for it.  Software like [FreeSwitch](https://freeswitch.org/) may help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. These kind of devices are really out-dated nowadays. But I'm forced to use them in my project unfortunately. Is there any way to achieve the above goal using a **GSM modem** also? (I mean waiting for an incoming call from a dial-up phone and and accept it and after that receive the code that the user enters on the keypad).

Comment: Yeah, lots more stuff is being done with GSM modems.  I will add a bit more to my answer

Comment: So I can build an sniffer for a dial-up connection between a phone and its network using 2 GSM modem? (One of them receive the call and the code, and after processing them, refer them to the other GSM modem and that second modem sends them to the real target finally)